# Построение поверхности по уравнению

Tags: opengl, геометрия

Стоит задача построить поверхность в OpenGL (но это не суть какой инструментарий). Поверхность задана функцией, с синусами, косинусами.

Главная проблема в том, что я вовсе не понимаю как правильно эту поверхность строить. Самая простая идея которая пришла в голову, это разбить область построения на сетку, и соединить узлы как прямоугольники. Но тут же появляется проблема: что если точки лежат в разной плоскости. По определению, любая плоскость определяется тремя точками, а значит треугольником. Значит надо как то разбивать на треугольники. Но пока что в голову ничто не пришло.

Может есть какие идеи? Разбить как сетку, а потом построить как треугольники тоже не совсем подходит. Возьмем четыре точки, (0, 1, 0), (0, -1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, -1, 0). Так вот, получается, что по этим четырем точкам, мы можем построить аж целых 4 треугольника. И какой из них выбрать тогда. Такой подход мне не совсем подходит, или я слишком много требую в данном случаи?

Answer (score 2):

Не усложняйте себе задачу )

По 4 точкам можно построить только 2 варианта пары треугольников (иначе они скрещиваются и это не поверхность). Выбирайте любую ориентацию. При достаточно плотной сетке, разницы не будет.

Также, если вас интересует наглядность отображения, то рисуйте поверхность из пар треугольников, а ребра показывайте только от пары вместе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, да, я это и имел в виду. По 4 точкам можно построить 4 треугольника, но из них только две пары образуют поверхность.